# Problema con separar listas

Tags: python, lista

estoy haciendo un ejercicio el cuál me pide calcular el dígito verificador de una cédula, pero tengo un problema, en la letra me piden que la lista pasada cómo parámetro sea una lista de enteros sin comas, y no una lista de enteros con coma, mi pregunta es, cómo puedo pasar por parámetro una lista de enteros sin comas y poder realizar la multiplicación con la lista de valores, la cuál está separada con comas
mi código es este:

```
def ultimodigito(cedula):
    valores=[2,9,8,7,6,3,4]
    listavacia=[]
    digitoverificador=0
    for i in range (len(cedula)):
        a=valores[i]*cedula[i]
        listavacia.append(a)
    suma=sum(listavacia)
    resto=suma%10
    if resto==0:
        digitoverificador+=resto
    else:
        if resto!=0:
            resto=10-resto
            digitoverificador+=resto
    return digitoverificador
    
print(ultimodigito([1,2,3,4,5,6,7]))
```

cuándo invoco a la función me gustaría que la lista 1234567 la pudiera pasar sin las comas, cómo una lista de enteros

Comment: Para escribir una lista si o si necesitas comas. Estas seguro de que interpretaste bien el ejercicio? Quiza se refiere a que los numeros no son decimales, es decir, no tiene coma (ya se, decir "enteros sin coma" es redundante, pero aun asi es posible)

Comment: Para convertir "123" en [1,2,3] usa `[int(x) for x in cedula]`